# Can a Java object pass itself an instance of itself

Tags: java

I have a class called `SomeClass` which has a method called `methodToCall(SomeClass o)`

If I instantiate SomeClass like this:

```
SomeClass itsObject = new SomeClass();
```

Can I then do this:

```
itsObject.methodToCall(itsObject);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Absolutely. How that will behave will depend on the implementation, of course.

Just as an example, `equals` is defined to be reflexive, such that:

```
x.equals(x)
```

should always return `true` (assuming `x` is non-null).

Comment: I would suggest you to  add some thing about `this` in your answer

Comment: @org.life.java: I would based on the subject, but the *text* of the question doesn't actually bear it out. It's talking about passing something to the same object, not *that object* doing it.

Comment: It would add cherry over cake :)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can.

One (contrived) example:

```
BigInteger one = BigInteger.ONE;
BigInteger two = one.add(one);
```

(You should try these things in your IDE - it takes less time than writing a question)

Comment: Agreed, but I figure if the question is generic and has a descriptive title, it serves as a reference for others in future.

Comment: +1 for the "try it" thing.  So much of SO is questions that could have been settled in far less time by **trying** it instead of asking a question and waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It would be by default,
you don't need to specify it. in method body you can refer it as `this`

Note: method should not be static

and if you want to externally specify you can do it simple.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is nothing that prevents you doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this, as long as methodToCall accepts an object of type SomeClass(or a class deriving from SomeClass) as a parameter:

```
public void methodToCall(SomeClass parameter){.....}
```

You can call it from outside your class:

```
yourObject.methodToCall(yourObject)
```

or from within the class, using *this* :

```
public class SomeClass{
    ...
    public void AnotherMethod(SomeClass parameter)
    {
       this.methodToCall(this);
    }
    ...
}
```